# Google Chrome cast to Google Home on different network

Tags: networking, google-chrome, audio-streaming

Is there a way to cast to Google Home from Chrome browser, if the smart speaker is on the different network? I know Google says devices should be on the same network, but maybe there are some hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

To make devices to appear on the same subnet, you may [create a network bridge](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections). This way devices, even connected to separate physical interfaces of the server, may be actually in one subnet.

But there is not only a requirement for devices to be in the same subnet.

I've investigated that the Google Home not just merely accepts packets from a casting device. It also wants to be able to **ping the caster** (ICMP) and send packets to the multicast address **224.0.0.251**, over **UDP** protocol, to port **5353**.

Google casting support page says that traffic to Google Home should be unrestricted, but says nothing about the fact that the smart speaker should be able to send some packets over the network, too.

I've unfirewalled this traffic and now casting to Google Home works.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a different network, are you saying on a different physical network, different subnet, or separated by VLAN?

If you are different physical networks, I don't think it's going to work without creating using VPN. If you're on separate subnets or VLANs you could create static routes between them.

Comment: Well, the Chrome is on a PC on a wired network, and the Google Home is on a Wi-Fi.

Comment: Okay, I would say that you're on the same subnet and, therefore, network. Verify that with a wired device and wireless device. Get their IP addresses make sure they are both in the same /24 block, so 192.168.1.XXX.

Comment: No, devices are actually on different subnets, the PC is 192.168.10.2 and Google Home is on 192.168.150.9. Both devices have common gateway/server, so static route is possible.